# How to extract the saved passwords on your phone?

Tags: gmail, password

EDIT: Sorry for the uninformative title, it kept saying "This title looks like spam!" so I had to rearrange the title a few times before I could post this.

I forgot my gmail password and the only way I can get into it is with my android phone which seems to remain logged in. Well actually I read how it works, the android gmail app stores an authentication token in a .db file, then it sends that authentication token to gmail, and only then gmail sends the password back. So if an attacker was to hack your phone, all they'd get is the authentication token.

Now I know I probably answered my own question there, that its impossible to get the password from the phone, but I just wanted to ask it anyway in case theres something I haven't taken into consideration.

Comment: Are you able to auto-login using a web browser (e.g chrome) or its only through the gmail app?

Comment: If you need help recovering your Gmail account (rather than extracting passwords from your phone), I'd be happy to help. Just reply back `@owlswipe`.